# Easy class questions on joining

Tags: python, class

I need to have the output look like this: "The sum of (num1) and (num2) is (num3) and (num1)>(num2)." or visa versa with which number is bigger. I cannot figure out how to append or join these strings together without getting error codes. The + and \ are not working to join them and I even tried to make another string with a new name for it and join them all together.

CODE:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter number 1:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter number 2:"))
num3 = num1 + num2
print (" The sum of", (num1))
print ("and", (num2))
print ("is:", (num3))
the_text = "".join([ "The sum of", (num1), "and", (num2), "=" (num3)])



if num1 > num2:
    print ("The number", (num1))
    print (">")
    print (num2)

elif num2 > num1:
    print ("The numer", (num2))
    print (">")
    print (num1)

else:
    print (num1)
    print ("=")
    print (num2)


input ("Press enter to close.")
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the relevant language(s). I'm guessing... [tag:python]?

Comment: yes it was for python but I finally got it figured out.

Comment: num1 = int(input("Enter number 1:"))
num11 = num1.__str__()
num2 = int(input("Enter number 2:"))
num22 = num2.__str__()
num3 =  num1 + num2
num4 = num3.__str__()
print ("The sum of " + (num11) + " and " + (num22) + " is " + (num4))
print ("AND")
if num1 > num2:
    print ((num11) + " > " + (num22))
    
elif num2 > num1:
    print ((num22) + " > " + (num11))
    
else:
    print ((num11) + " = " + (num22))

    
input ("Press enter to close.")

Comment: sorry that didnt come up like code. This is my first time every using this site. I am not sure how to make comments look like code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the language required is Python,

```
comparison_result = ""
if num1 > num2:
    comparison_result = ">"
elif num1 < num2:
    comparison_result = "<"
else:
    comparison_result = "="
the_text = "The sum of " + str(num1) + " and " + str(num2) + " is " + str(num1 + num2) + " and " + str(num1) + comparison_result + str(num2)
```

You just need to typecast the `int` as `str`.

Comment: so comparison_result changes the int to a str? I had to look it up on how to convert and add extra numbers to figure it out.

Comment: `comparison_result` is a string which represents the result of the comparison.  It could just as easily be "is greater than", "is less than", or "is equal to".  What changes the `int  to a `str` is the cast (`str(num1)`)

Comment: No. `num1` is an `int` type. Doing `str(num1)` changes it to the type `str` which can be concatenated using `+`.

Comment: I created a new number and converted to a string. Thank you!

Comment: You can click the check-mark button next to the answer to show that the answer helped solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatting:

```
cmp_char = ""
if a > b:
    cmp_char = ">"
elif a < b:
    cmp_char = "<"
else:
    cmp_char = "="

print "The sum of {} and {} is {} and {} {} {}".format(num1, num2, num3, num1, cmp_char, num2)
```